# Powershell not able to find an AD Group by name

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0

I'm trying something very simple I want to extract all users of particular groups.
I have a list of groups and it works fine for most of them but for some It just doesn't find the group.

I can see it with the name using Active Directory Users and Computers but powershell complains with the following error:

```
Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'Test_OPIT_Opy Operators' under: 'DC=bla,DC=ad,DC=bla,DC=com'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupMember 'Test_OPIT_Opy Operators'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Test_OPIT_Opy Operators:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADIdentityNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGro 
   upMember
```

I tried the following nothing works:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*Test_OPIT_Opy Operators*"} |select -exp samaccountname

Get-ADGroup 'Test_OPIT_Opy Operators'

Get-ADGroup -identity 'Test_OPIT_Opy Operators'
```

Also the funny thing is if I try to list the groups that a member of this group is this group is not showing up.

Example :

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership  usrname | select name
```

Thank you

Comment: [1] what actual version or versions of PoSh do you need to work with? please remove the others. [2] are you certain that the group name is _exactly_ what you are using? can you find it with `Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -like '*OPIT*'"`?

Comment: This might be a new group and the system may not have synchronized yet. Try adding the`Server` parameter and use the same dc as you are connected to with Active Directory Users and Computers.

Comment: Hi Lee, Here's the powershell Verison Name                                                                                                                                                           
PSVersion                      4.0 I'm sure the name is exactly the same. I can see it in Active Directory UI. The group is at least 4 years old. I tried with the filter it doesn't find anything.

Comment: What account are you using to open your PowerShell console? Does that account have permission to see that object in AD?

Comment: @Evo You might be conflating the group's `displayName` (the attribute AD displays be default in GUI tools) the with `name` of the underlying object. What is the full distinguished name of the object?

Comment: Hi Theo, Powershell is connected to the same domain controller as Active Directory Users and computers. The UI finds the group powershell doesn't.  In the error I've also noticed  when it says under DC= is not showing the correct DC name I don't understand why.

Comment: Hi Mathias R. Jessen, I do see the Canonical name of the object in GUI and it's exactly the same as Display Name / Name.

Comment: "PowerShell is connected to the same domain controller"/"DC= is not showing the correct DC name" - those statements seem to be contradictory. I don't think you're looking in PowerShell where you think you're looking.

Comment: Hi Bill, yes they are contradictory. But it works for the rest of the groups with no problem. Why it doesn't work for this one? The account I'm using has enough privileges.

Comment: What is the group type and group scope?

Comment: Group type security , Scope is Domain Local.

Comment: I did it manually it's so frustrating..

Comment: Can you find the group if you specify a domain controller (with `-Server` parameter) of the domain the group is in?

Comment: Powershell is actually connected to the same domain as the GUI. No difference.

Comment: @Evo Does `Get-ADRootDSE` return the expected domain information?

Comment: But you said the domain name in the PowerShell output is different. So we're obviously missing some pieces of information.

Comment: What exactly did you mean by "I did it manually it's so frustrating"?

Comment: Right-click the domain in the ADUC and check what server it is connected to. Use that same server in PowerShell via the `-Server` parameter. Find the group in ADUC, right-click and look in the properties for the `Name` of that group. Use that **EXACT** name in the `Get-ADGroup`'s Identity parameter. (copy/paste). P.S. If you want to respond to someone in a comment, start with `@` followed by the persons name. That way, they will be notified

Comment: Thanks All. That was the reason. As soon I specify the AD name under -server everything worked as expected. I don't see an option to mark this question as resolved.